# alpine linux docker image, console encoding trouble

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux

I have a scala app that is running in docker container. I use image 'develar/java' which is based on alpine linux. My app is working, but i don't see cyrillic logs. Here what i have:

```
docker logs -f myApp 
22:22:08.152 [main] INFO  application  - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
22:22:09.213 [main] INFO  play.api.db.DefaultDBApi  - Database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db
22:22:09.627 [main] INFO  p.a.l.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider  - Starting application default Akka system: application
22:22:09.698 [main] INFO  application  - ????????????? ??????? ???????
22:22:09.722 [main] INFO  application  - ????????????? ??????? 'direct
22:22:09.734 [main] INFO  application  - ????????????? ??????? 'adwords
22:22:09.761 [main] INFO  play.api.Play$  - Application started (Prod)
22:22:09.866 [main] INFO  play.core.server.NettyServer$  - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

But logs that are delivered to elasticsearch server are ok. How can i force alpine linux to work with utf-8?

Comment: put in your Dockerfile something like  `ENV LANG en_US.utf8`

Comment: I've runned container with -e "LANG=en_US.utf8" but it didn't help. When i type **env** command inside container i see that variable: "LANG=en_US.utf8"

Comment: do you have a reproducer, a Dockerfile, a `docker run` command, a github with enough data?

Comment: try `setup-keymap` and  `setup-timezone` from http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_setup_scripts

Comment: I don't have a reproducer, i need time to make it for you, sorry. Thanks for link!

Comment: can you do a test, with in your alpine Dockerfile `ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
`

Answer (score 2):

`develar/java` has an old bug of an old glibc 2.21 package. Andy Shinn (the creator and maintainer of glibc package for Alpine) and I have [resolved this a long time ago](https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/5) in glibc 2.23 packaging, which I have integrated into [`frolvlad/alpine-glibc`](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/), which is the base image for [`frolvlad/alpine-oraclejre8`](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejre8/). Just replace `devalar/java` with `frolvlad/alpine-oraclejre8:slim` and you should be fine.